# Magento Store Massive Error

Tags: magento2, error, home

I recently checked the magento site i am working on. And was presented with this gigantic error message from magento.

https://pastebin.com/Y0hGEx1m

The only task which was performed before this error appeared was a re-index from the cli. The admin panel is still accessible but i am unsure what is causing this error.

Comment: Looks like whoever is the creator of the Bizkick module is creating quite a few invalid or misplaced elements in some layout xml file. Can you post the contents of the files that contain "bizkick" elements?

Comment: The wierd thing is, the site has been fully functional using a bizkick theme for a few months now. Its only suddenly decided to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Went into the themes files under /app/design/frontend/ParentTheme/ChildTheme/*
Located layout xml files, and wherever there are occurences such as:

as="Bizkick Above" replaced with as="Bizkick_Above"

This is because spaces are not allowed in the theme files.